# Batch File to open a custom Directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that asks the user for a directory, and opens that directory. But, it keeps opening "My Documents" instead! Here's my Code:

`@echo off
set /p DIR= "Enter a Directory: "
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%DIR%"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing

```
@echo off
set "dir="
set /p "DIR=Enter a Directory: "
if defined DIR start "" "%DIR%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it and it gave me an error message:  "Windows cannot find 'C:/Program'!

Comment: Thats easy to fix. Just move the quote before the E to before DIR.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do it (if you want it in one line):

```
@echo off & set /p "DIR=Enter a Directory: " && Call explorer /n/select,"%DIR%"
```

Normal script:

```
@echo off
set /p "DIR=Enter a Directory: " && (
    call Explorer /n/select,"%%DIR%%"
)
```

PS: The && is to avoid to open explorer if the user pressed enter without typed a folder. the Call command is not needed in the normal example if you don't agrupate the line.

See here for more info about explorer switches: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457